# When added 3 fields to the MySQL it didn't show some fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have added 3 fields to MySQL, but it have shown only "feedback" value, other were empty. 
Here is my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO `feedback` (`name`, `email`, `feedback`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($feedback)."')")) {
echo 'Success!';
} else {
  echo mysql_error();
  exit;
}

<form action="ajax.php" method="post" class="postcard">
 <textarea type="text" value="" id="theMessage" name="feedback" required></textarea>
 <input type="text" id="input2" name="name">
 <input type="text" id="input3" name="email">
</form>
```

Got my name field - TEXT(30), email and feedback - VARCHAR

Comment: a lot of wrong here, but lets see the form anyway.

Comment: @nogad, edited my question

Comment: some debugging: `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: @nogad edited my question again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$feedback =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feedback']);

if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO `feedback` (`name`, `email`, `feedback`) VALUES ('$name','$email', '$feedback')")) {
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Also you check your field length. If your value length more than field length may be fail to insert.

Comment: the same thing :(

Comment: check your table structure.

Answer (score -1):

Try without quotation marks.

```
"INSERT INTO `feedback` (name, email, feedback) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($feedback)."')"))
```

Comment: this will do nothing

Comment: The same, it adds only feedback field, other - empty

Comment: @nogad Why? Then you propound a solution. Link with an example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: @user221283 Write a static field test that well inserted into database.